# c# Serialize and json

Tags: c#, arrays, json

I tried to deserialize:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ContentModel>("{\"Message\":\"asdf\",\"Attachments\":[\"dummy.pdf\"，\"unnamed.jpg\"]}"),
```

Where the content model:

```
public class ContentModel
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string ContentType { get; set; }
    public string[] Attachments { get; set; }
}
```

But the deserialization failed due to the array of string in the `Attachments`.

Answer (score 2):

The character you are using in between of `\"dummy.pdf\"` and `\"unnamed.jpg\"` is not really a comma! it just looks like to be a comma!
remove it and replace it with `,` .

**Update**
As @dbc mentioned, The character being used currently in your code is [FULLWIDTH COMMA](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ff0c/index.htm).

Answer (score 0):

The fixed JSON is

```
 JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ContentModel>("{\"Message\":\"asdf\",\"Attachments\":[\"dummy.pdf\",\"unnamed.jpg\"]}"),
```

Test applet:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var y = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ContentModel>("{\"Message\":\"asdf\",\"Attachments\":[\"dummy.pdf\",\"unnamed.jpg\"]}");
            Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(y, Formatting.Indented));

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class ContentModel
    {
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public string ContentType { get; set; }
        public string[] Attachments { get; set; }
    }
}
```